# Has this sorting algorithm been invented? Is it linear time complexity?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, object, time-complexity

I am not sure how objects natively sort numbers, and whether that affects the time complexity of this algorithm. That why I wonder if this is linear (**O(n)**).

I am aware that the space complexity is terrible.

This is my code:

```
const objSort = (arr) => {
  let storage = {};
  let sorted = [];
  let entries;

  arr.forEach((num) => {
    storage[num] ? storage[num]++ : storage[num] = 1;
  });

  entries = Object.entries(storage);

  entries.forEach(([ key, value ]) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < value; i++) {
      sorted.push(+key);
    }
  });

  return sorted;
};
```

Comment: this is a bubble sort -- it is O(n^2)

Comment: @hogan nope. This is no sorting at all.

Comment: @JonasW. -- right if he had an if and swap on the push line then it would be.

Answer (score 3):

> I am not sure about how objects sort numbers automatically

Nope they do not. Object key order is not guaranteed. Therefore, you actually dont sort anything :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the gist of a potentially linear sort.  However, it depends on several implementation requirements.

First, I want to make sure that I understand the approach:

- Start with a blank `storage` structure.  This will count the occurrences of each element of `arr`, indexed by the element itself.  For instance, given the input string "abaczaz", `storage` would finish as `{'a': 3, 'b':1, 'c':1, 'z':2}`
- Iterate through `storage`; for each entry, emit the indicated quantity of the listed element.  For the current example, this would produce "aaabczz".

Each of these iterations is length **N**, a linear solution.  *However*, note the requirements for this to work:

- You must have a mapping of objects to indexes that is **O(1)**.
- That mapping must embody the sorting order for the objects.
- Access time into and from `storage` must be **O(1)**.
- Iteration through `storage` must be **O(N)**.

For this last point, most solutions are **O(range(object))**, a number large enough to be impractical.  For instance, to sort 64-bit integers, you would need an array of length 2^64 memory locations, and you'd iterate through all 2^64 integers to emit the sorted array.

Granted, the fixed bound makes this technically **O(1)**, but for a *very* large value of `1`.  :-)  In theoretical terms, it's **O(log (max(arr) - min(arr))**, as the memory requirement depends on the value range.  This drives your overall complexity to **O(n log n)**`

**FINALLY ...**

Yes, this sort has already been implemented.  I've had it as an interview question.